# Cx_Freeze and youtube_dl missing modules Windows

Tags: python, cx-freeze, youtube-dl

I am using Cx_Freeze to create an executable from a python script (just one file : mp3InThePocket.py) on Windows 10. Everything was working when I tried it on Ubuntu. A lot of issues occured when using windows. I managed to solve loads of them but I am running into a last one : there seem to have missing modules when building with Cx_Freeze.
My setup.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Python 3

import sys, os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includes = ["youtube_dl", "urllib", "os", "sys", "time", "re"]
excludes = []
packages = []
path = []


exe = Executable(
    script="mp3InThePocket.py",
    icon="./icone.ico",
)


setup(
    name="mp3InThePocket",
    version="1.00",
    description="",
    author="LDV",
    options = {"build_exe": {"includes": includes,
             "excludes": excludes,
             "packages": packages,
             "path": path
             }
       },
    executables=[exe]
)
```

Here is what I get when building :

```
Missing modules:                                                                                 
? BaseHTTPServer imported from youtube_dl.compat                                                 
? Cookie imported from youtube_dl.compat                                                         
? Crypto.Cipher imported from youtube_dl.downloader.hls                                          
? HTMLParser imported from youtube_dl.compat                                                     
? __main__ imported from bdb, pdb                                                                
? _dummy_threading imported from dummy_threading                                                 
? _frozen_importlib imported from importlib, importlib.abc                                       
? _frozen_importlib_external imported from importlib, importlib._bootstrap, 
importlib.abc        ? _posixsubprocess imported from subprocess                                                      
? _scproxy imported from urllib.request                                                          
? ce imported from os                                                                            
? cookielib imported from youtube_dl.compat                                                      
? fcntl imported from pty, youtube_dl.utils                                                      
? future_builtins imported from youtube_dl.compat                                                
? grp imported from shutil, tarfile                                                              
? htmlentitydefs imported from youtube_dl.compat                                                 
? httplib imported from youtube_dl.compat                                                        
? java.lang imported from platform                                                               
? netbios imported from uuid                                                                     
? org.python.core imported from copy
....                                                             

This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform.
```

The weird thing is that the executable is running fine when launched from the console but not when clicking on it. (an error occurs with youtube_dl, due to, I think, those missing dependencies)

The program itself is running fine when launched on its own (before the build with cx_freeze) with Python.

Another thing to know is that I needed to specify the PATH to ffmpeg (which I downloaded seperately) in Windows env variables so that youtube_dl works with the original python script.

I installed Cx Freeze from the source directory (cloning from github and installing)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I am getting same problem a long time ago, then I figured it out these cx_freeze and pyinstaller which we use to convert .py file into .exe works on windows because exe file will contain the instructions related to the specific format of os. don't you remember that  we need some libraries for the py to exe

Comment: @babygame0ver So what do you suggest I do ?

Comment: I would like to say create the file using pyinstaller on windows first of all, that's my preference instead of cx_freeze. But if you find cx_freeze easy ,that's all on you. Use windows to convert your .py file into executable and if you want to run the executable on ubuntu/linux distributions then use the wine package on the linux machine, then you can able to run the .exe file easily .

Comment: `The weird thing is that the executable is running fine when launched from the console but not when clicking on it` -- Does your script use any relative file paths? If that's the case, try creating a shortcut for your executable and, in the shortcut properties, in the 'Start in' field put `"C:\Path\To\ExecutableDir"`

Comment: @sytech it uses relative file paths. Creating the shortcut did not solve the issue